# Applying for a Japanese visa on the road as a non resident

Tags: visas, japan, thailand, bangkok, indonesian-citizens

I'm currently in Bangkok (with tourist visa), as part of my long term travel.
I'd like to go to Japan in one or two month, and as an Indonesian national, I need a visa to enter Japan (I have non biometric passport/epassport).

Being in long term travel, I would be the best for me to get a visa on the road, and I'm thinking of applying here in Bangkok.
However, from this information: http://www.th.emb-japan.go.jp/en/consular/visa1.htm, I need to be a Thai resident.

Can I apply for Japanese visa here in Bangkok?
If I can't, is there any nearby countries where I can apply for Japanese visa as a non resident?
Or must I just go back to Jakarta and make an arrangement there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website you link to states:

> In principle, you should have a legitimate long term residency in
>   Thailand. [...] If you came to Thailand only as a tourist and plan to
>   apply for a Japanese visa, please contact JVAC or the Embassy by
>   phone.

So the answer is generally **no**, you can't apply in Thailand unless you live there, you will need to return home.  Of course you can try your luck and call, but unless there are good circumstances (family emergency etc) I doubt they will let you apply.

My understanding is also that this general policy applies to all Japanese embassies worldwide.

Comment: I see. I think I will just go back to Indonesia and upgrade my passport to e-passport, as I will get 15 days free visa per entry to Japan. I think it would be a good investment. Thanks!